# What is the point of associations between classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

So from my current understanding associations give classes access to methods which allow them to create relationships with other classes. This gives an inner consistency to the models; but how is this really relevant to the end user? I mean, yeah, the developer can now more easily link to like-classes in a more streamlined way, but couldn't the developer do all that with HTML/JS/View? The methods from association seem overly redundant.

I apologize if my understanding is off or my view of this (pun intended) is overly simplistic, I am just trying to wrap my head around the inner mechanics of this system. Could someone explain the point of associations and the role they play to me? 10+ bonus points if you can explain it using a metaphor or ELI5. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I already [read the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). It says "Associations are a set of macro-like class methods for tying objects together through foreign keys" Which I understand. I just want to understand more concretely exactly what they are for because "tying object together" is very vague and as a newbie it really offers me no real understanding.

Comment: Perhaps this will help a picture is worth 1k words
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a practical perspective: without relationships and associations, you cannot store your data into a database.

Imagine that you are building a blog. Your blog have more than one author.
One author can have many posts, and a post have many comments.

How can you show this data in your blog without associations, or even better,
without knowing which post was made by which author, which comment was made in which post
and so on.

But with associations in rails, if you want to know the author of a post you can simply do:

```
post = Post.find(:id)
post.author
```

And if you want to know all the posts made by an author you can:

```
author = Author.find(:id)
author.posts
```

Comment: You could do that without Rails associations too, though.

Comment: He's asking from a Rails perspective.

Comment: My point was that you state you can't do it without the associations. The benefit is that the framework normalizes relational data access and eliminates the need to do the work manually via lower-level interfaces. The point is re-use and convention.

Answer (score 2):

"Overly redundant?" Doing the same work in every app would be *more* redundant.

"Typing objects together" is about as concise as it gets: Except in trivial cases, most data has other, related, different data. Consider a tree-based commenting system.

- The site has users.
- Users have comments.
- Comments have parents (and children).

These are related data. Those relationships are abstracted by Rails via associations.

Yes, of course you could do everything manually, but that's true with any framework.

The point is that there is a lot of duplication regarding associative data.